# Javascript setCookie function not working for checkbox values

Tags: javascript

I'm not able to store values from my checkboxes into cookies, using the 'setCookie' function.

The same function works fine for textboxes, radiobuttons and dropdown-lists.

Could anyone help me figure this out and correct my code?

```js
var today = new Date();
var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days

function setCookie(name, value)
{
 document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
}

function storeValues()
{
 setCookie("Language", myForm.Language.value);
 return true;
}

function validate()
{
    var cbvalues = [];
    var cbs = document.myForm.Language;
    var cbLen = cbs.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < cbLen; i++) {
    if (cbs[i].checked) {
      cbvalues.push(cbs[i].value);
    }
  }
  if (cbvalues.length == 0)
  {
  alert( "Please choose your languages!" );
  return false;
  }  
  alert( "You selected: " + cbvalues.join(', ') + ".");
  return( storeValues() );
}
```

```html
<form action="form_submitted.html" name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validate());">
<table>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="Language" value="English">English</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="Language" value="French">French</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="Language" value="German">German</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td align="right"></td>
   <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: change `cbvalues.push(cbs[i].value);` to  `cbvalues.push(cbs[i].checked);`

Comment: 1) you have several checkboxes with the same name 2) the value of a checkbox is set, so you will get it was the checkbox checked or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is where you are trying to set the cookie value.

```
setCookie("Language", myForm.Language.value);
```

myForm.Language is an array of inputs which you'll have to loop through and get the values of the *checked* checkboxes - similar to how you are doing in the `validate()` method. I've modified your code to pass this value from `validate()` method to the `setCookie()` method.

```js
var today = new Date();
var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days

function setCookie(name, value)
{
 document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
}

function storeValues(values)
{
 setCookie("Language", values);
 return true;
}

function validate()
{
    var cbvalues = [];
    var cbs = document.myForm.Language;
    var cbLen = cbs.length;
    var values;
    for (var i = 0; i < cbLen; i++) {
    if (cbs[i].checked) {
      cbvalues.push(cbs[i].value);
    }
  }
  if (cbvalues.length == 0)
  {
  alert( "Please choose your languages!" );
  return false;
  }
  values = cbvalues.join(', ');
  alert( "You selected: " + values + ".");
  return( storeValues(values) );
}
```

```html
<form action="form_submitted.html" name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validate());">
<table>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="Language" value="English">English</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="Language" value="French">French</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="Language" value="German">German</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td align="right"></td>
   <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: This solution is definitely working and was the simplest too.

Comment: Can you accept mine as the answer if it helped you? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
function getAllCheckedValues(checkbox)
{ 
    let ret = "";
    for(let index=0 ;index < checkbox.length;index++)
    {
        let check = checkbox[index]; 
        if(check.checked)
        { 
            if(ret!="")
            {
                ret+=",";
            }
            ret+= check.value;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}


function storeValues(selected)
{
 setCookie("Language",selected);
 return true;
}

function validate()
{
    let selected = getAllCheckedValues(document.myForm.Language);

    if (selected)
    {
        alert( "Please choose your languages!" );
        return false;
    }  
    alert( "You selected: " + selected + ".");
    return( storeValues(selected) );
}
```

Comment: I tried out this solution and it's definitely working. Thank you for showing a great way of doing it. There was a minor error in the code though, and after correction: <code>function validate()
{
    let selected = getAllCheckedValues(document.myForm.Language);

    if (selected)
    {
    alert( "You selected: " + selected + ".");
    return( storeValues(selected) );
    }  

    alert( "Please choose your languages!" );
    return false;
}</code>